# How to filter this json by nested value using `jq` and print the parent key identifier?

Tags: json, jq

Suppose I have this json

```
{
  "sha256:0085b5379bf1baeb4a430128782440fe636938aa739f6a5ecc4152a22f19b08b": {
    "imageSizeBytes": "596515805",
    "layerId": "",
    "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
    "tag": [
      "python-3-toolchain-0.1.2"
    ],
    "timeCreatedMs": "1564631021992",
    "timeUploadedMs": "1564631067325"
  },
  "sha256:1ec7631f74a3d6d37bf9194c13854f33315260ae1f27347263dd0a8974ee82bb": {
    "imageSizeBytes": "513574770",
    "layerId": "",
    "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
    "tag": [
      "python-2-toolchain-latest"
    ],
    "timeCreatedMs": "1535447023647",
    "timeUploadedMs": "1535447042373"
  }
}
```

I want to select the image information (as well as the sha256 digest) with certain tag. Example: I want to select only `tag == "python-2-toolchain-latest"`, so it prints this json (with json reformat)

```
 {
    "digest": "sha256:1ec7631f74a3d6d37bf9194c13854f33315260ae1f27347263dd0a8974ee82bb",
    "imageSizeBytes": "513574770",
    "layerId": "",
    "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
    "tag": [
      "python-2-toolchain-latest"
    ],
    "timeCreatedMs": "1535447023647",
    "timeUploadedMs": "1535447042373"
  }
```

I have tried various approach, and being stuck at how to reference the sha256 key information.

Answer (score 1):

A possible `jq` program to accomplish your goal:

```
# Embed the final result into an array to get a valid JSON output
[
    # Convert the input object into a list of { key, value } objects
    to_entries[]

    # Keep only the objects that contain the desired tag
    # The .tag field may contain multiple tags and the desired one can be at any position
    | select(.value.tag | contains(["python-2-toolchain-latest"]))

    # Add the key into the value object into the .digest property
    | .value.digest = .key

    # Keep only the values (the modified objects)
    | .value

# That's all, folks
]
```

[Try it online!](https://jqplay.org/s/Adam3XZiKB)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straightforward and concise but efficient solution:

```
keys_unsorted[] as $k
| .[$k] as $value
| select($value.tag[0] ==  "python-2-toolchain-latest")
| {digest: $k} + $value
```

Comment: @AgungPratama - It's just four lines of code, so it would probably be best for both of us if you used the jq manual to read about `keys_unsorted`, `as`, `select`, and object addition (`+`).

Comment: @peak I liked your solution except it only finds the `"python…"` thing at index `0` in the array. Also, I like `to_entries` to get the the *key-value* pairs.

Comment: @ColinFraizer - If one wants all matches, just omit the `0`!  FWIW, I chose `keys_unsorted` as that yields a (slightly) more efficient solution.

Comment: @peak Thanks! I didn't really consider just using `select($value.tag[] == "python-2-toolchain-latest")`. It works, but it's hard for me to wrap my head around it. It looks like an operator with two operands, but I guess isn't.

Answer (score 0):

here is what i worked up.    i assumed that the tag array could contain more than a single entry...

```
.
|to_entries[]
|.key as $k
|.value as $v
|.value.tag[]
|select(.=="python-2-toolchain-latest")
[ { "digest": ($k) }, $v ] | add
```

after seeing the peak answer, I like the last line like this better:

```
[ { "digest": ($k) } + $v ]
```

If the tag can occur twice, then this would output the same record twice.  there must be a better way to simply check if "python-2-toolchain-latest" is in the tag[] array.  My jq foo is not strong enough.

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
.
| to_entries
| .[]
| select(.value.tag | contains(["python-2-toolchain-latest"]))
| { digest: .key } + .value
```

- I put your example data in a file I named `pratama-1.json`.
- I ran the following command and got this output.

  ```
  $ jq '. | to_entries | .[] | select(.value.tag | contains(["python-2-toolchain-latest"])) | { digest: .key } + .value' pratama-1.json
  {
    "digest": "sha256:1ec7631f74a3d6d37bf9194c13854f33315260ae1f27347263dd0a8974ee82bb",
    "imageSizeBytes": "513574770",
    "layerId": "",
    "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
    "tag": [
      "python-2-toolchain-latest"
    ],
    "timeCreatedMs": "1535447023647",
    "timeUploadedMs": "1535447042373"
  }
  ```

## Breaking this down

You can think of a `jq` program as analogous to a `sh` pipeline,
except:
- with `sh` (or `bash`), each stage of the pipeline (that is,
  each command between `|` s) has a stream of bytes (often just text) as
  its input and output;
- with `jq`, each stage has a stream of *JSON
  values* as its inputs and outputs.

1. The simplest `jq` program is simply `.`:

   - If the input is the JSON value `true`, the output is `true`.
   - If the input is the JSON value `[ true, 3.1416, "foo" ]` (an array value), the output is the same.
   - If the inputs are the three JSON values `true`, `3.1416`, and `"foo"` (a boolean, a number, and a string),
     then the three outputs will be that boolean, that number, and that string.
2. At the beginning of my script, the `.` just represents the input value, which in this case is
   that JSON object you included in your question.
3. The next stage is `to_entries`:

   - It converts a JSON object into a JSON array of JSON objects.  For an input like:

     ```
     {
       "a": 3.1416,
       "b": false
     }
     ```

     into an array like this:

     ```
     [
       {
         "key": "a",
         "value": 3.1416
       },
       {
         "key": "b",
         "value": false
       }
     ]
     ```
4. The next stage is `.[]`, which is a `jq` operator that turns one JSON value into many:

   - If the input is a single JSON array like `[ true, 3.1416, "foo" ]`, the *three* ouptuts are
     the JSON values `true`, `3.1416`, and `"foo"`.
   - In our case, it unwraps the JSON array around all those *key-value* objects so we can many
     output values instead of one JSON array output value.
5. The next stage is the `select(…)`:

   - For each input value, it evaluates the expression in its parentheses and "passes along" that input
     as an output if the expression is true.
   - For example, for the three inputs `true`, `3.1416`, and `"foo"`, `select(type == "string")`
     would have only one ouput: the string `"foo"`.
   - My `select(…)` has two inputs:

     1. A JSON object `{ "key": "sha256:008…", "value": { "imageSizeBytes": … } }` **AND**
     2. A JSON object `{ "key" :"sha256:1ec…", "value": { "imageSizeBytes": … } }`.
   - Inside my `select(…)`, I use a subexpression that is itself a `jq` pipeline: `.value.tag | contains(["python-2-toolchain-latest"])`:

     1. The first part `.value.tag` yields the value of the field with key `"tag"` in each of those objects.  For your
        example data, each value is a JSON array.
     2. The `contains([…])` part evalues to `true` for input JSON array values if all the values in its argument JSON array `[…]`
        are members of that input JSON array value.

        - Some examples

        ```
        $ jq '. | contains([ "foo" ])' <<< '[ true, 3.1416, "foo" ]'
        true
        $ jq '. | contains([ "foo", true ])' <<< '[ true, 3.1416, "foo" ]'
        true
        $ jq '. | contains([ "foo", true, null ])' <<< '[ true, 3.1416, "foo" ]'
        false
        $ jq '. | contains([ "foo", true, false ])' <<< '[ true, 3.1416, "foo" ]'
        false
        $ jq '. | contains([ "foo", true, null ])' <<< '[ true, 3.1416, "foo" ]'
        false
        ```
   - So, the expression in my `select(…)` evaluates to `true` for each imput JSON object that has a
     key named `"value"` with a JSON sub-object value that has a key named `"tag"` with a JSON array value
     that contains an element with the JSON string value "python-2-toolchain-latest".
   - For each input where the expression inside `select(…)` is `true`, that input value becomes one of the output values.
   - For your example data, this is only the second sub-object: `{ "key": "sha256:1ec…", "value": { … } }`.
6. The last stage of my pipeline is a `jq` expression that looks like a JSON object.

   - `{ digest: .key }` says for each input value, output a JSON object value with:

     - a key named `"digest"` **AND**
     - the value of that key should be the value associated with the input JSON object's key named `"key"`.
     - Since our input is the JSON object `{ "key": "sha256:1ec…", … }`, this would give us the output JSON
       object `{ "digest": "sha256:1ec…" }`.
   - But we want other stuff in our output JSON object too: we want to add in the JSON object value associated with
     the key `"value"` in our input object.  We get that by adding `+ .value`.
   - The `jq` `+` operator when used with JSON object values "merges" its operands JSON objects into a single output JSON object,
     e.g. `{ "a": true } + { "b": 3.1416 }` yields `{ "a": true, "b": 3.1416 }`.